# Element not found on phantomjs But working fine on chrome

Tags: selenium, automation, phantomjs, headless-browser

I am using `phantomjs` version `1.1.0` and  `phantomjs-2.1.1.exe` for `windows`.

[CONTINUE ACTIVATED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtGCY.png)

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="right-align" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 6px; margin-left: 20px; flex-grow: 100;">
<div>
<a class="t-next-pd continue-to-query button-text" style="background-color: rgb(11, 197, 216); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 40px; padding: 0px 16px; text-decoration: none; display: inline-flex; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 4px; z-index: 100; cursor: pointer; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 1px solid rgb(11, 197, 216); width: 100%;">
<span style="display: inline-block;">CONTINUE</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to locate the element using

1. relative xpath for both the classes : `.//*[@class='t-next-pd continue-to-query button-text']`, `.//*[@class='right-align']`
2. by text
3. by partial text
4. by link
5. by cssSelector
6. relative xpath with text
7. By absolute xpath (Last priority)
8. By ClassName
9. javascript executor
10. Implicit wait and Explicit wait

NOTHING SEEMS TO WORK

The CONTINUE button only gets activated when I enter name and age.
This is the code when CONTINUE button is not activated.

```
<div class="right-align" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 6px; margin-left: 20px; flex-grow: 100;">
<div>
<a class="button-text" disabled="" style="background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 40px; padding: 0px 16px; display: inline-flex; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 4px; z-index: 100; cursor: pointer; align-items: center; justify-content: center; width: 100%;">
<span style="display: inline-block;">CONTINUE</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[CONTINUE DEACTIVATED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aATur.png)

Comment: I used this `a.t-next-pd.continue-to-query.button-text` on the activated button. This is a CSS Selector and it works fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

After filling in the details wait for a second. PhantomJS immediately searches for the activated continue button. It's most likely a timing issue. The continue button might take 500ms to 1 second to become active.

So when PhantomJS starts searching for the activated button it cannot find it because if doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

If you're using Python use `time.sleep(2)`. It pauses for 2 second. This gives the DOM time to change the inactivated code to the activated code.

I used this `a.t-next-pd.continue-to-query.button-text` to find the activated button. This is a CSS Selector and it worked fine in my test case :)

Convert this to the language you're using. I'm using Python:-

```
# code
# to
# fill the form
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.t-next-pd.continue-to-query.button-text')
```

Comment: Still not working. language : Java. 
I have already used :-
1. driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
2. TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
3. Thread.sleep(1000);
All of them are not working.

Comment: @SaurabhNagpal Can you share more code from the webpage and your Java code as well? I tried with whatever you gave and it works on my side. It'll help people find the issue. If the issue still persists after you've shared the code I'll make a chat room where we can discuss it in detail :)